# Slow down the rate of requests in Vue.js updated method in Django web application

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue.js view in a Django template. Vue pulls the data to display in the view from a Django Rest Framework endpoint. My code follows:

```
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ["[%", "%]"],
        data: {
            dedicated_server: [],
        },
        created() {
            fetch('/api/dedicated-server/{{ object.id }}/')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.dedicated_server = json;
                })
        },
        updated() {
            /* TODO: Try and limit the number of requests to the API */
            fetch('/api/dedicated-server/{{ object.id }}/')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.dedicated_server = json
                })
        },
    });
```

As you can see I have an updated method which polls the Restful endpoint to update the page if the data changes. This all works fine but it seems to poll the Restful API endpoint about 3 to 5 times a second. This is fine in development but if I have 100 people visiting this page then it is going to kill my server with requests.

Is there a way to limit the number of times Vue.js checks to see if the data has been updated? It would be great if you could say check once every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to run every 5 seconds. Set it up in `created` and you don't need to worry about `updated`.

```
    setInterval(() => 
        fetch('/api/dedicated-server/{{ object.id }}/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.dedicated_server = json;
            }),
        5000);
```